# How to verify root from adb shell?

Tags: batch-file, adb, root

In my script I have the following code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('adb -s devicename shell su') do @set res=%%a
echo %res%
```

But I get no output. How to properly check for `su` availability from a `batch` script?

Comment: your script never goes past the 1st line - `adb -s devicename shell su` command opens an interactive shell session which never finishes (until user types `exit` or presses `ctrl+C`)

Comment: Thank you for the information! I got it.I'm a newbie in android.I need to verify root and The result from adb shell su.How to modify my script?@Alex P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set uid=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('adb -s devicename shell "su 0 id -u 2>/dev/null"') do set uid=%%a
echo %uid%
```

`%uid%` will be `0` if `su` is available